# Android override file for flavour

Tags: android

In my android app I have a file that I want to override for a specific flavor.
My structure:
[image: Structure]

However when I build the funki flavour I still see that the Computer class from main is used.
In my build.gradle I have:

```
productFlavors {
    somename{
        resValue "string", "app_name", "some name"
    }
    funki {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Funki App"
        applicationIdSuffix ".funki"

    } 
}
```

Every build I see that the Computer file from main is used.
All the other overrides e,g, res files are overriden based on the flavor i build.
How can I override a class for a specific flavor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking the productflavor inside the code like:

```
if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("funki")){
```

Based on the if/else I execute my desired code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting a "duplicate class" build error — at least, that used to be the behavior. You cannot override a Java/Kotlin class in a flavor.

What you *can* do is remove the Java/Kotlin class from the `main` source set and have it in all of your flavors. So, move `Computer.java` from `main` to `somename`, and keep your other `Computer.java` in `funki`.